# How to setup TFS 2010 portal to be accessed from outside

Tags: sharepoint-designer, tfs

I have TFS 2010 integrated with SharePoint 2010 web application on port 80, I created team project and now i cant access it from outside at all.

Details:

-I have a port forward which forward port 2080(outside) to port 80(inside) cause port 80 is actually busy in the network.

-Server Name is:TFS2010

-I have a domain lets say : domainex.com

I know I have to set something in alternative access mapping and IIS binding but I don't know which values i should set.

Can any one tell me exactly what i should setup to everything so developer can right click team project from visual studio and choose show portal and get forwarded to the team project portal from outside the local network?

Comment: You may want to ask this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

In the SharePoint Web Application containing the TFS web sites, you need to add Public URL (http://domainex.com) to AAM (Alternate Access Mapping). You do this in Central Admin (http://CA_URL/_admin/AlternateUrlCollections.aspx). You can use any Zone you wish for the Public URL, probably Default is taken, so use some other that is not defined.

Then in IIS settings you need to add corresponding binding to the web site hosting SharePoint TFS sites.